# powered window and back windscreen wiper anomaly

Tags: battery, electronics, power-windows, windshield-wipers

### At first i thought it was random, then i realised that there is clearly a pattern:

1. I start the car then i check and **both the wiper and the window
   works as expected.**
2. **20-30-40 minutes down the road** i have checked again and **neither of them works.**
3. **Restart, wait 5 minutes** or so, and everything is **back to normal.**

Checked/replaced the fuses they are fine, also reconnected the switches for the powered windows. No effect unfortunately.

The car has the original battery, but it seems to be working great starts the engine with no problem even in the winter. So it seems pointless to replace.

### Do someone has any similar experiences with a vehicle?

---

**Car info**

2007 Opel Vivaro

2.0 CDTI (Diesel)

original battery, but it works great

no previous electrical issues whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

In most vehicles, the body control module (BCM) controls these things. Your switches just tell the BCM when to activate what. I'm not sure if that's what's wrong with your Opel, but it sounds like it might be. Also, have your battery checked professionally. It may have enough power to start the engine, but not enough to run the electronics correctly. A battery normally is only good for about 5 years. If yours is the original battery from 2007, you've gotten some great life out of it.